# Licence for android API demos?

Tags: android

I was trying to establish the licence of the API demos at developer.android.com as there were code segments I was planning to use (in a commercial context).

I found http://source.android.com/source/licenses.html but that seems to relate to the AOSP and the APIs themselves as opposed to the demos that have been put together.

Is anyone able to shed light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Api demos is part of the open source project and thus Apache 2 and free for commercial use.

https://github.com/android/platform_development/blob/10cb19aefec9b0b25bbe209ee1a2afc648ab46c3/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/animation/AnimationCloning.java

Comment: Fantastic, I checked a few classes and couldn't find more than  * Copyright (C) 2010 The Android Open Source Project